# The mechanism of the evolutionary rate hypothesis

Tags: ecology, macroevolution, biogeography

There are several hypotheses for explaining the latitudinal gradients in species diversity ([link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latitudinal_gradients_in_species_diversity)). Of which, the evolutionary rate hypothesis states that warm temperature increases the rate of speciation. I want to know why warm temperature facilitates evolution.

This is not a question, but... some other hypotheses specifically discuss how a factor influences the rate of evolution (e.g., the size hypothesis discusses how large area can promote speciation). I think temperature hypothesis is a better name for the evolutionary rate hypothesis.

Comment: Related question: [*Is there a hypothesis that attempts to explain patterns of species richness along all three energy-related environmental gradients?*](http://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/14472/is-there-a-hypothesis-that-attempts-to-explain-patterns-of-species-richness-alon/14480#14480)